# Body-parser to avoid "JSON.parse(body)"

Tags: javascript, express, middleware, chai

In express I can use a middleware called "body-parser" to automatically parse the incoming body.

Now that I do not have an express router to apply the middleware to, is it possible to somehow apply it to all requests in my chai test file? So that I can achieve the DRY principle.

I currently use this in every test:

```
it('login', done => {
    request.post('http://localhost:3000', (err, res, body) => {
        JSON.parse(body) // <-- I have to parse the body each time
        done();
    })
});
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb may I flag other comments for being stupid? I mean, he is marking my question as a duplicate of another question that clearly is distinct from mine. Are you suggesting that I should flag him for that?

Comment: if you think a comment is not reasonable, in this case a comment saying it's a dupe of a question that it's not raise a flag and say that. Don't say I think the comment is "stupid", be professional about it. Likewise you can leave a comment saying " I don't think this is a duplicate because bla bla " Just keep the comments professional. I agree, it wasn't a dupe of that question. I didn't like how you said it. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) library. And if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want `request` to automatically parse your response body via `JSON.parse`.

The documentation explains how to do that under https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

> `json` - sets `body` to JSON representation of value and adds `Content-type: application/json` header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON.

So your code should be something like:

```
request.post({url: 'http://localhost:3000', json: true}, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(res)
    console.log(body)
})
```

Untested, but that's what I gather from reading the docs.